# Vagrant with VPN connection over host computer

Tags: vpn, vagrant

I'm trying to get my Vagrant CentOS box connected to VPN thru my host computer. I followed this: https://gist.github.com/mitchellh/1277049

but I still can't connect to the VPN only hosts.

I'm on Vagrant version 1.3.5 and CentOS release 6.4.

Vagrant configs: `config.vm.network :public_network` and, as noted by the link above, I have

```
vb.cusotomize["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
```

With this setup I don't get any errors, it just doesn't seem to be working. I can reach hosts on my host machine but not thru my VM. When the VM is booting I choose my `2) en0: Ethernet 1` connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Gist [1277049](https://gist.github.com/mitchellh/1277049) is using default NAT networking for the Vagrant box.

However, you are using Public Network (Bridged) with your en0. That's why it is NOT working.

> NOTE: I don't think you can bridge to a VPN connection (virtual adaptors, no driver). By using NAT, you are able to access the systems on the other side of the VPN connection.

To fix, just comment out the `config.vm.network :public_network` line. By default it'll use NAT and the box should be able to access whatever the host is capable of.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I removed the Gist line and made it a private network with a static ip and now it is working great.

Answer (score 8):

As Terry Wang answered, remove public_network and as then follow this answer https://superuser.com/questions/542709/vagrant-share-host-vpn-with-guest

The newer versions of Vagrant will only use host as dns with this:

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
end
```